# The origins of the Copying/Generation garbage collection algorithm

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

Could anyone tell me who is the inventors of Copying GC and Generation GC?

Answer (score 0):

The inventor of Copying algorithm is Marvin L. Minsky, and the Generation algorithm's are Henry Lieberman and Carl Hewitt.